# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React and API

Tags: reactjs, api

I am very new to react and I am trying to bring in data from a food2fork api but I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

if i **undo this code**, the error was none. this code is **main place** to occur error

```js
  {recipes.map (recipe => {
    return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
    />;
  })}
```

Full Page of **RecipeList.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe';
import RecipeSearch from './RecipeSearch';

export default class RecipeList extends Component {
    render() {
        const { recipes } = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <RecipeSearch />
                <h1>Recipe List</h1>
                <div className="container my-5">
                    {/* title */}
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 text-center text-uppercase mb-3">
                            <h1 className="text-slanted">Recipe List</h1> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* end title */}
                    <div className="row">
                        {recipes.map (recipe => {
                            return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
                            />;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Recipe />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

In [App.js](https://github.com/zinmyoswe/React-Recipe-Search-Project/blob/master/src/App.js):

```
render(){
    console.log(this.state.recipes);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RecipeList />
        <RecipeDetails />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
 }
```

Comment: ```this.props.recipes``` is undefined. Please add the script where you're importing RecipeList component.

Comment: i tried as u say change `this.props` To `this.props.recipes` , but it is still showing error

Comment: That changes makes no sense since you're already destructuring props. What I mean is to edit your post and add the part of your code that calls your component, like this ```<RecipeList .../>```

Comment: can u add the code of the component that is using this component?

Comment: u mean `App.js` or other js files in component folder it is need to be add

Comment: Somewhere in your project's scripts you're using <RecipeList ...> to render the RecipeList component. It might be App.js if this is a small proyect, but it depends on your project.

Comment: Sir, i added App.js link, `<RecipeList />` is already declare in this App.js

Comment: Somewhere, in your project, you're using this component.  As defined, the component says "I want this thing `recipes` that's a prop.  But where you're using this component, you're not using this prop at all.

Comment: Found your error, check my answer.

Comment: Thank, bro Rasnick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking it that you are keeping the recipes data in `this.state.recipes` in App.js

You need to pass it as props to `<RecipeList` component to use it as props there.

So in your App.js just do this

```
render(){
  console.log(this.state.recipes);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes}  />
      <RecipeDetails />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not passing any prop to RecipeList. 
Change this in App.js

```js
 return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
        <RecipeDetails />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Second, in RecipeList.js, render it only when the async function completes.
Change:

```js
{recipes.map (recipe => {
  return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
    />;
  })}
```

To:

```js
{recipes ? recipes.map (recipe => {
  return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
    />;
  }) : null
}}
```